# Oracle system time as float

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a query to a database that is part of an enterprise database application. There is a datetime column called DATETIME that is stored as a float, e.g. "41869.6514596064". I want to restrict my results to those rows where DATETIME is greater than or equal to the current time.

How can I get the current system time formatted as a float?

Comment: What date does 41869.6514596064 represent?  Normally, systems that represent a date as a number are representing a certain number of "ticks" (generally seconds or milliseconds) from a fixed start date (often 1/1/1970).  Since you're apparently not using a standard start date or tick size, you'll have to tell us how to convert the current time into a float (or vice versa) or give us enough data to be able to reverse engineer the calculation.

Comment: It's the number of days since 1/1/1900.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you only care about the date to the second (rather than introducing milliseconds) You can get the number of days since 1/1/1900 just by subtracting that constant date from `sysdate`

```
SELECT sysdate - date '1900-01-01' days_since_jan_1_1900
  FROM dual;
```